# AMPScript stopping loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a break function in AMPScript? I have following code snippet and would like to end the 'For' loop if the condition is met. Currently the code will transverse the whole DE.

How can I fix this?

```
%%[ set @DELookup = lookuprows('DE', 'SubscriberKey', SubscriberKey) 
if rowcount(@DELookup) >= 1 then
for @i = 1 to rowcount(@DELookup) do
set @instanceRow = row(@DELookup, @i)
set @ID = field(@instanceRow, 'columnID')
if not empty(@ID)then
// DO something
]%%
%%[else]%% %%[endif]%%
%%[next @i]%% %%[else]%% %%[endif]%%
]%%
```

Comment: This outputs something?  The AMPScript block tags are not matching.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple trick to brack the For Loop -

```
%%[ 
SET @Data = LookUpRows('DE','SubscriberKey',@SubscriberKey)  
SET @Count = RowCount(@Data)

IF @Count > 0 Then
    For @i = 1 To @Count Do
        SET @ID = Field(Row(@Data,@i),'columnID')
            IF Not Empty(@ID) Then
                Do Somthing....
                SET @Count = @i
            EndIF
    Next @i
EndIF
]%%
```

Comment: Please take some time to review [answer] and add some context , link references as well as an explanation as to why your answer works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.  If the condition is met, it will stop the for-loop.

```
%%[ 
set @DELookup = lookuprows('DE', 'SubscriberKey', @SubscriberKey)

if rowcount(@DELookup) >= 1 then

    for @i = 1 to rowcount(@DELookup) do

        set @instanceRow = row(@DELookup, @i)
        set @ID = field(@instanceRow, 'columnID')

        if not empty(@ID)then
            /* DO something */
        endif

    next @i

endif
]%%
```

Comment: Hi Adam, If I have 2 or more rows that met the condition, only the second row get executed. I would like to exit from the loop once condition is met so that 1st row will be executed and 2nd row later.